# How to get symbols to our dev machines with NuGet on Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, symbols

The end scenario I am trying to tackle is debugging a NuGet package we develop and publish to our feed in Azure DevOps, when referenced from a different package. E.g. package `A` is released via a pipeline to an Azure DevOps NuGet feed. I am using it from package `B`, and want to be able to debug code inside `A` using Visual Studio.

Problem is `dotnet pack --include-symbols` does not include `A`'s symbols into the .nupkg. Instead, it puts them into .symbols.nupkg, which are not getting pushed by `dotnet push` to our DevOps feed. There's a conflict unless I explicitly exclude .symbols.nupkg:

> Response status code does not indicate success: 409 (Conflict - The feed already contains 'A 0.0.0-REDACTED'. (DevOps Activity ID: A7965FB9-B458-43F9-8973-FD0B6E7F1138)).

The question is twofold:

1. Is there a supported and well documented way to get debug symbols (and, preferably sources) automatically loaded in Visual Studio for a NuGet package build by CI in Azure DevOps?
2. If what I am trying to do is the correct way, how do I deal with .symbols.nupkg?

Comment: Did you look at the docs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/symbols?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a supported and well documented way to get debug symbols (and, preferably sources) automatically loaded in Visual Studio for a NuGet package build by CI in Azure DevOps?

I have read a great blog before, it gives a detailed steps how to debugging ASP.NET Core Nuget Packages with AzureDevOps/VSTS Symbol Server, you can check if it helps you:

Ticket: [ASP.NET Core Debugging Nuget Packages with AzureDevOps | VSTS Symbol Server](https://www.liftrtech.net/home/blog?name=ASP.NET-Core-Debugging-Nuget-Packages-with-AzureDevOps-VSTS-Symbol-Server)

> If what I am trying to do is the correct way, how do I deal with
>   .symbols.nupkg?

I am afraid not, we need use the task [Index Sources & Publish Symbols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/index-sources-publish-symbols?view=azure-devops) to index your source code and optionally publish symbols to the Package Management symbol server or a file share.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The docs @zivkan linked are the place to start. The Azure DevOps symbol server doesn't currently support .snupkgs.